# MFC Treeview : How to check if Treeview already contain particular child node?

Tags: c++, mfc

In MFC Treeview control, how i can check condition if particular child node is already present in treeview?

My requirement is like if particular child node is present in treeview dont add it again in that treeview...

Any code snippet is welcome ........
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to call the methods ItemHasChildren/GetChildItem and GetNextSiblingItem.

There is a code example for the GetNextSiblingItem help on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTreeCtrl GetItem method in order to get the inforamtion of perticular item in Tree view.